# How to ignore the safe area when using keyboardLayoutGuide?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, constraints

I have a full screen list and want to use the new keyboardLayoutGuide constraint, but by default it uses the safe area inset. How can I disable this so my list goes all the way to the bottom of the screen when the keyboard is not shown?

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
   collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
   collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
   collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  view.trailingAnchor)
])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usesBottomSafeArea` is a new property introduced in iOS 17 to address this. Watch [Keep up with the keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10281) for more info.

```swift
view.keyboardLayoutGuide.usesBottomSafeArea = false
        
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
   collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
   collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
   collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  view.trailingAnchor)
])
```